# LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Deploying rails app to Heroku, which performs fine locally. Steps taken to get to error:

1. `heroku create`
2. Add Postgress and Redis add-ons in Heroku
3. `git push heroku master`
4. `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Resulting in the following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/app/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:27:in `<main>'
```

After adding buildpack: `heroku/ruby`, new error appeared

```
2019-07-25T19:51:03.023594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-25T19:51:06.471239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails s`
2019-07-25T19:51:08.138269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-25T19:51:08.058366+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found
2019-07-25T19:51:08.118175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-07-25T19:49:32+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-deep-66970 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.14 sample#load-avg-5m=0.225 sample#load-avg-15m=0.225 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.19835 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13422688kB sample#memory-cached=495752kB sample#memory-redis=308864bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-25T19:52:24+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-deep-66970 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.155 sample#load-avg-5m=0.215 sample#load-avg-15m=0.22 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.35 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13427216kB sample#memory-cached=495820kB sample#memory-redis=308864bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-25T19:52:24+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-deep-66970 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.195 sample#load-avg-5m=0.21 sample#load-avg-15m=0.22 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.22689 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13406080kB sample#memory-cached=497256kB sample#memory-redis=308864bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-25T19:55:54+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-deep-66970 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.17 sample#load-avg-5m=0.19 sample#load-avg-15m=0.21 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.3719 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13410204kB sample#memory-cached=496804kB sample#memory-redis=308864bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-25T19:59:41+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-deep-66970 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.17 sample#load-avg-5m=0.175 sample#load-avg-15m=0.2 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.11765 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13406140kB sample#memory-cached=496988kB sample#memory-redis=308864bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-25T19:59:41+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-deep-66970 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.185 sample#load-avg-5m=0.2 sample#load-avg-15m=0.21 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.22951 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13420264kB sample#memory-cached=499128kB sample#memory-redis=308864bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-25T20:02:32+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-deep-66970 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.165 sample#load-avg-5m=0.19 sample#load-avg-15m=0.205 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13418800kB sample#memory-cached=499128kB sample#memory-redis=308864bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-25T20:03:25.371221+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stormy-harbor-54816.herokuapp.com request_id=431808e4-cb80-4d01-8d4c-bbcf4f6e3478 fwd="2.219.90.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-25T20:03:28.719807+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stormy-harbor-54816.herokuapp.com request_id=386cedea-3b8c-4bb7-aea6-249884707184 fwd="2.219.90.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Whats the output of `heroku buildpacks`?

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-activestorage-preview

Comment: is that the result of command? If yes, try pushing changes after this: heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby

Comment: @Mobeen, have added it. A new error appeared listed above.

Comment: Have you provisioned Redis?

Comment: Your app is started btw,  Its crashing after starting now :)

Comment: Yes, it's provisioned. I ran `heroku addons | grep heroku-redis` and it shows up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197009/discussion-between-mobeen-and-ruben-portz).